# Java Download file from url with download dialog

Tags: javascript, java, download

I want to download a file from a url which initially shows some html, then displays a download dialog after 2-3 seconds. Obviously if I do this:

```
     try {
            URL url = new URL("http://my.url");
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",
                    Integer.toString(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
            con.setReadTimeout(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            con.setConnectTimeout(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            con.connect();

            bis = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream(), 4096);

            byteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(bis);

            FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File("myFile"), byteArray);


        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
```

I will save the displayed .html rather than the file that is displayed in the save dialog.
How should I change the code in order to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the dialog just has some javascript which waits a couple seconds and requests the  file download embedded in the dialog somewhere.

If this is the case, if you figure out what element the 'real download' is contained in, you can use JSoup, or any other html parser library to scrape the link out of the page.

You obviously only have to do that if the download link is generated dynamically.

After doing what rossa suggests, I'd suggest setting javascript breakpoints in the dialog window to figure out how exactly the real url is getting requested.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the url is the exact location of the file you want to download? I mean, is there any redirect - you can check in your browser and use HTTP headers extension for instance to check what's going on behind the scene.